# Как заменить содержимое элементов массива содержимым переменной?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Имеется скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const TEXT_BACKUP = $("p").text();
  console.log("Исходный текст <<TEXT_BACKUP>>", TEXT_BACKUP);

  const SYMBOL_ARRAY = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '?', '}', '{'];
  console.log("Массив символов <<SYMBOL_ARRAY>>", SYMBOL_ARRAY);
  console.log(SYMBOL_ARRAY.length);

  var TextArray = TEXT_BACKUP.split('');
  console.log("Массив из исходгого текста <<TextArray>>", TextArray);
  console.log("Длинна массива <<TextArray>>", TextArray.length);

  for (i = 0; i <= TextArray.length; i++) {
    let text_random = Math.floor(0 + Math.random() * (TextArray.length + 1 - 0));
    let symbol_random = Math.floor(0 + Math.random() * (SYMBOL_ARRAY.length - 0));
    if (TextArray[text_random] != " ") {
      let text = SYMBOL_ARRAY[symbol_random];
      console.log(text);
    }
  }
})
```

Как сделать так чтобы в `TextArray` содержимое элементов массива с номерами `TextRandom` заменялось на `text`?

Comment: `TextArray[TextRandom] = text` ?

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych невероятно. Я столько вариантов перепробовал а оказалось что все так просто. Добавьте ответом чтобы я мог отметить как правильный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Содержимое элемента массива заменяется простым присваиванием по индексу :

```
TextArray[TextRandom] = text;
```